# offline server status control

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

good work if you want to check the status of remote servers being turned on or off.
I communicate with sql linkled with remote servers. but when the server is down, the timeout is a problem for my pen.
I want to see whether the answer is closed immediately.

```
Public Sub Treeview1_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles Treeview1.NodeMouseClick
        Dim ksname As String
        ksname = e.Node.Text
        oleCMD = New OleDbCommand("exec sp_testlinkedserver " & ksname.ToString, Con)
        oleCMD.CommandTimeout = 2
        Try
            Dim oledbReader1 As OleDbDataReader = oleCMD.ExecuteReader()
            e.Node.ImageIndex = 1
            e.Node.SelectedImageIndex = 1
            e.Node.Checked = True   
        Catch ex As Exception
            e.Node.SelectedImageIndex = 2
            e.Node.ImageIndex = 2
            e.Node.Checked = False          
           End Try
    End Sub
```

the command timeout I set with the above codes does not work
I also tried connect timeout and query timeout times in the properties of sql links did not work.

Thank you from now